# Test method fails when @Transactional

Tags: java, oracle, testing, spring-boot, junit

I am writing my end-to-end tests for an application. One of those tests will verify that when some required input is missing, it will not persist the data to the database. All is running fine, untill I decided to annotate my test class with `@Transactional`, since I don't need to persist the results when the tests are finished. The moment I add the `@Transactional`annotation, the application is suddenly ok with a non-null field to be null.

**How the database is set up:**

```
create table MY_TABLE
(
    MY_FIELD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

**The corresponding model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyObject {

    @Column(name = "MY_FIELD", nullable = false)
    private String MyField = null;
}
```

**Saving goes via the service layer:**

```
@Service
public class MyAppServiceImpl implements MyAppService {

    @Inject
    private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;  //this interface extends CrudRepository<MyObject , Long>

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public MyObject save(MyObject myObject) {
        return myObjectRepository.save(myObject);
    }
}
```

In the resource layer, the value of myField is set to `NULL`, so at the moment the data is persisted, I should receive an ORA-error

```
@Controller
public class MyAppResourceImpl implements MyAppResource {

    @Inject
    private MyAppService myAppService;

    public ResponseEntity doPost(@RequestBody String xml) {
        MyObject myobject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setMyField(null);
        try {
            myAppService.save(myObject);
            return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (SomeExceptions e) {
            return new ResponseEntity("Could not save", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, the test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//@Transactional
public class MyAppResourceImplEndToEndTest {
    @Inject
    private MyAppResourceImpl myAppResource;

    @Test
    public void testWithFieldNull() throws Exception {
         ResponseEntity response = myAppResource.doPost("some-xml");
         Assertions.assertThat(response.GetStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

This test works, as expected, but other tests persist data into the database. This is not the behavior I wanted, so I annotated the test class with `@Transactional`. Now no tests persist their results to the database, but this specific test method fails because

```
Expected :400
Actual   :201
```

Why does the `@Transactional` annotation suddenly cause `NULL` values to be persisted in `NOT NULL` columns?

Comment: Because nothing is persisted... The transaction commits AFTER the final method (the method that started the transaction) has finished. You moved that from your service to your unit test.

Comment: The save() method from the respository should throw the exception none the less. The result is inserted in the database, just not commited.

Comment: No it isn't inserted... The call to save does nothing until it decides it is time to flush and that is after/until commit.

Comment: What you're saying is that, when you make your test Transactional, all of your tests that make modifications to the database are suddenly unreliable?

Comment: As long as there is no flushing to the database yes as no constraints will be checked.

Comment: you can let the DB check not-null values by adding @ Transactional, add @ Rollback(true) [ can be added to methods and classes just like @ Transactional ] in case of test (which should not add data permanently to the DB), without @ Transactional, the database doesn't do anything

Comment: @JurgenDeLandsheer I'm not following what you're trying to say.  Adding @ Rollback instead of @ Transactional on class level makes the test methods persist data to the database again. Combined with @ Transactional I keep getting my issue, as I expected.

Comment: @M.Deinum The CrudRepository seems to lack a flush() method. I tried to force it by making a select of the recently persisted object. The select succeeds but the result of the test remains the same.

Comment: our Test classes (which run isolated) contain at the top of the testclass: @ Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@ Rollback(true)

Comment: Adding @rollback without ‘@Transactional’ makes your test non transactional again, reinstating your original behavior. Adding a flush should work, but not with a select of the current object. That will only hit the 1st level cache.